# Domain name problem with VPS

Tags: dns

I want to host a website on a VPS. I have everything working except for domain name resolution.

The VPS has no control panel. It just has a CLI.

I did go to my domain registrar which provides DNS service and I added the following

> A mysite.com  the.server.ip.address.here

Do I have to do something on the server side?

Comment: Is the server ubuntu server?

Comment: @AmithKK yes it is

Comment: If you recently added the domain it can take 24 hours to propogate.

Comment: @bodhi.zazen I added it about 4 hours ago. So I just wait to see if it works? I didn't do anything about dns in my server.

Comment: I would wait 24 hours ;)

Comment: @bodhi.zazen Waiting really works sometimes.

Comment: Do is it working now ?

Comment: check your domain on http://www.intodns.com/

Comment: And i would recommend you that you install zpanel on your VPS...its very easy to setup and its web based management for your domain ..